# Unhandled JavaScript exception terminates MSAppHost/WWAHost.exe

Tags: javascript, cordova, win-universal-app

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Throw test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="throw 'does this abort the app'">CRASH</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code when run as a Universal Windows app (MSAppHost/3.0) (WWAHost.exe) terminates the app (exit code 0x3).  Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

I have tried adding a window onerror handler and it doesn't prevent the app terminating.

```
window.onerror = function(e) { return false; }
```

*edit* This is a Cordova based windows 10 mobile project running an existing html5 application. To have to add try catch around every event handler would be an incredible amount of work.

*edit* In JavaScript an exception should abort only the execution context for the event not the entire app.

Comment: While I stand by my answer around global exception handlers, have you tried `return true` at all? It seems that's the way to get `onerror` to stop bubbling the exception.

Comment: no I haven't I will try now...

Comment: You are a star!  That's what I was doing wrong, returning false not true.  Can you add your comment as a question so I can accept it.  Thanks

Comment: I've edited the info into my answer already :)

Comment: You could write a JavaScript function (say `function wrapExceptions(innerFunction);`) that would take a function as its single parameter and do the try-catch exception wrapping for you with a single call to it. And return true or false based on whether it's been handled or not, if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

The best way to prevent this behaviour is to **handle the exception**.  Global exception handlers are generally frowned upon, other than maybe logging the error, as they can't possibly deal with every exception possible, and will just result in the application ending up in an unknown state.

If you can't handle the exception in a reliable fashion somewhere relevant, it implies that you don't know what the issue is, and your application will probably start to fail in other ways due to the unknown state - at this point it may as well stop running entirely.

---

All that said, in HTML, you can `return true` from the `onerror` handler rather than `false` to prevent the exception from bubbling further.  For example, this will log the error in the console but not display an uncaught error:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    console.log('a');
    throw "oops";
    console.log('b');
});
window.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log('error', e);
    return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
test
</button>
```

But this will both log the error, then display an uncaught error:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    console.log('a');
    throw "oops";
    console.log('b');
});
window.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log('error', e);
    //don't return true
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
test
</button>
```

Comment: This is an existing html5 app. To have to add try catch around every execution context would be an incredible amount of work. In JavaScript an exception should abort only the execution context for the event not the entire app.

Comment: @Austin Even if it did only abort the current execution context, there's no guarantees what state things have been left in, because by definition it's been unhandled and not cleaned up after.  Without proper exception handling, any non-trivial application will get into unknown states and cause other issues.

Comment: A badly written event handler could possibly leave the app in an undefined state, but that's just because its a badly written event handler.  In cases where updating application could leave the application in an unknown state, then yes ofc, a try catch handler should be used, but in cases where it doesn't it is quite normal (in html5/javascript) to ignore the (possibility of an) exception because it only affects that particular event, and doesn't leave the application in an unknown state.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to adding a catch clause? 
This allows you to catch errors and not crash the application. This would handle the exception properly

Comment: This is an existing html5 app. To have to add try catch around every execution context would be an incredible amount of work. In JavaScript an exception should abort only the execution context for the event not the entire app.